# Не обновляется компонент dash_table.DataTable после обновления страницы в dash

Tags: python, table, datatable, dash

Я столкнулась с проблемой обновления таблицы в dash.
Опишу кратко работу программы: на странице есть таблица, которая изначально пустая; пользователи загружают свои табличные данные, содержание компонента обновляется. После обновления страницы желательно, чтобы содержимое таблицы исчезало.
Я попробовала передать в app.layout функцию, которая очищает таблицу и снова перестраивает страницу (ссылка на источник: https://dash.plotly.com/live-updates). Ничего не вышло.

Функция построения таблицы:

```
def build_table(data):
return html.Div([
    dash_table.DataTable(
        data=data.to_dict('records'),
        columns=[{'name': i, 'id': i, 'type': 'numeric',
                  'format': Format(precision=2, scheme=Scheme.fixed, trim=Trim.yes)} for i in data.columns],
            
        id='table_data'
    )
])
```

Объявление компонента:

```
html.Div(
    children=[build_table(df)],
    id='output-data-upload',
)
```

Может быть проблема при обновлении таблицы во время загрузки файла, но я не имею представления.

```
# -------Перепостроение таблицы (включая обработку пропущенных значений)-------
@app.callback([Output('output-data-upload', 'children'),
               Output('calc-block', 'style'),
               Output('body-error-upload', 'children')],
              [Input('upload-data', 'contents'),
               Input('submit-NA', 'n_clicks')],
              State('upload-data', 'filename'),
              State('table_data', 'data'),
              State('table_data', 'columns'))
def update_output(list_of_contents, n_clicks, list_of_names, data, columns):
    ctx_id = dash.callback_context.triggered_id
    style = {'display': 'none'}
    if ctx_id == "upload-data":
        if list_of_contents is not None:
            if len(list_of_contents) > 1:
                return dash.no_update, style, out_error("Было прикреплено больше одного файла")
            children = [
                parse_contents(c, n) for c, n in
                zip(list_of_contents, list_of_names)]
            style = {'display': 'block'}
...
```

Смотрела свойства таблицы, так же не нашла ничего путного.
Если кому-то нужен полный код, ссылка на репозиторий: https://github.com/eclerchig/CalcMedian_Project

Буду очень рада хотя бы маленьким догадкам

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Не совсем понял в чём у вас проблема...

1. как вариант попробуйте добавить в callback свойство
   prevent_initial_call=True:

   @app.callback(
   Output("first_output_2", "children"),
   Output("second_output_2", "children"),
   Input("button_2", "n_clicks"), prevent_initial_call=True)
2. Добавьте на страницу кнопку по типа такой [Boolean Switch](https://dash.plotly.com/dash-daq/booleanswitch) и условие внутри callback - если True возвращаем пользовательские данные, если False - пустую таблицу. Пользователь включает кнопку и взаимодействует с приложением. После обновления страницы кнопка должна вернуться в исходное положение.

Comment: Спасибо большое, первый вариант решил проблему)